# How can I prove $P^{-1}ABP=BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ square matrices, with $\operatorname{det}(A) \ne  0$.
>
> Prove that  $AB$ is similar to $BA$.

Do I need to prove there is a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}ABP=BA$？

Comment: What does the $det(A)\ne 0$ imply about the invertibility of A? After that, a clever choice of P will do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without words:

$$BA=A^{-1}\left(AB\right)A$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about it.  If such an invertible matrix P did exist, then: $$P^{-1}ABP=BA \iff ABP=PBA$$Try to make an educated guess as to what matrix $P$ should be. How do you know your guess is valid?

Comment: $P=A^{-1}$? then we have $ABA^{-1}=B$?

Comment: So close! Maybe not $P=A^{-1}$, but $P=\ldots$

Comment: I think $P!=B^{-1}$, since $B$ maybe not invertible.